# Saving ArrayList values to XML C#

Tags: c#, arraylist, streamreader, streamwriter

I have ArrayList nabídka, I have to save everything from this ArrayList to XML file using stream writer and on starting application load the XML file to ArrayList with stream reader. Does anybody know how to do it? (Yes, I know that I shouldn not use ArrayList, but i must complete this project with it.)

Comment: Which format for XML file? What did you try so far? Where exactly you have problems with that?

Comment: See to XElement it`s really easy.

Comment: You should try first and start some Googling...and describe your efforts also..

Comment: Your school teacher may very well be watching this post. ;-)

Comment: @SonerGönül: He said something about that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heres an example of how it might be implemented

```
  ArrayList sampleList = new ArrayList();
    sampleList.Add(" ");
    //Add your elements

    //StreamWriter initialized with append mode
    StreamWriter streamwriter = new StreamWriter(" INSERT PATH OF XML HERE ", true);

    for (int i = 0; i < sampleList.Count; i++)
    {
        //Elements are written into the file here, remember not to forget the xml structure 
        streamwriter.WriteLine(sampleList[i]);
    }

    //You have to close the streamwriter or you have to flush to make sure the text is saved
    streamwriter.Close();
```

I hope I could help you

Answer (score 0):

Also possible:

```
var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ArrayList), new Type[] { typeof(YourType) });
```

But for serializing it would be better to have a `List<t>`.
The benefit of serializing is the easy read in and that you even can share whole objects easily between languages/applications.